# How do I allow an AWS user to see an edit a DynamoDB created by another user

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have user Default and Default-2 both are inside the Admin Group with the AdministratorAccess permission, when I created a DynamoDB table with user Default, the table isn't visible to user Default-2.

I've tried to give user Default-2 the DynamoDBFullAccess policy but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using the console or cli to see the table? Are you sure there is no other policy attached to your user? Make sure you are looking at the right region as well

Comment: If listing tables results in an error then it's a permissions problem. Otherwise tables not being visible is almost always caused by a) wrong region or b) wrong AWS account.

Comment: With AdministratorAccess it should work. Chances are the user isn't part of the group or if he/she is, the Group doesn't have the correct policy attached.